# Anyone dealt with "KEI Journals"? What about the journal "Quarterly Physics Review"?

Tags: journals

I received an email from Dr. Naonori Ko wondering if I'd be interested in writing up a review article for a journal called "Quarterly Physics Review". I'm skeptical of new journals, but I also want to support a competitive journal publication market.

Has anyone had any dealing with "KEI Journals" or "Knowledge Enterprises Incorporated" or published in any of their journals (http://www.journals.ke-i.org/)?

Comment: KEI Journals was listed as a predatory publisher on the now-defunct Beall's List of Predatory Publishers. Looking at the description, "all disciplines of physics, with a focus on new research" [what research isn't new?] it doesn't seem like this new journal is filling any niche and is just trying to make money as broadly as possible.

Comment: Looking at their archives, the journal has published a total of two articles since 2015 (both in 2015). Neither full text appears to be available anywhere. I would run the other way, and quickly.

Comment: Great! Thanks Luigi. I guess I had previously used Beall's list as I expected to find that kind of information online. Weird that it has gone down and no one has acted to replace it?

Comment: Also see [With Beall's List gone, how can I tell if a journal is spam?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/83764/with-bealls-list-gone-how-can-i-tell-if-a-journal-is-spam)

Comment: (See the [help/on-topic]: "Can I ask about my specific situation?")

Answer (score 8, accepted):

KEI Journals was listed as a predatory publisher on the now-defunct Beall's List of Predatory Publishers. Looking at the description, "all disciplines of physics, with a focus on new research" [what research isn't new?] it doesn't seem like this new journal is filling any niche.

Looking at their archives, the journal has published a total of two articles since 2015 (both in 2015). Neither full text appears to be available anywhere. I would run the other way, and quickly.