# is David Publishing Company legit?

Tags: publishers, disreputable-publishers

I have an abstract presented by my colleague at a local conference. I got an email from a company called David Publishing Company claiming that they are interested in publishing our paper in the Journal of Materials Science and Engineering A, B they had?

Things look suspicious for me and I want to know if anyone has an idea about their legitimately as a science publisher. they claim to have a peer-reviewed process but they charge money as publication fees.

Comment: I would avoid that company. They were on the now defunct Beall's list of predatory publishers. Some good reading for you for the general case: [How do you judge the quality of a journal?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/101/17254) and [With Beall's List gone, how can I tell if a journal is spam?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/83764/17254).

Comment: I am closing this question since we do not evaluate individual publishers here. The duplicate may however help you to answer your question yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anyone who contacts you to publish is bad news.  My advice is to stick to journals from ACS, APS, and ACerS.  Maybe MRS or IEEE.  There are a few decent pubs in materials from Elsevier and Wiley, but even then you need to know who they are.  Don't submit something to a journal you don't know.

A dedicated conference proceedings is a different kettle of fish (like if this compay was retained to do conference proceedings), but even then I would try to give them some portion of or repackaging of work you publish in "real journals".

I can't find anything on the web from them either.  Which is bad also.  (Although if you included any links in your letter that would help us.)

Comment: "Anyone who contacts you to publish is bad news." That's a bit strong. There are legitimate invitations. However, legitimate invitations come from actual academics, not the publisher's staff.

Comment: OK, yeah.  I would definitely differentiate that sort of outreach.

Answer (score 4):

Their website is dubious:

- It contains a lot of typos, e.g.

> About Us
>
> David Publishing Company  (DPC) (originally as USA-China Business Review (Journal), Inc., USA), founded in 2001, is a professional English-language **academic journals and books publisher both in print and online versions**, which serves the world's research and scholarly communities. STEM (Scientific/Sciences, Technical, Engineering, Medicine) is our core theme. We are currently **receiving the submission of the fields**: Account & Accounting, Administration, Agriculture, Aviation Science, Business, Chemistry, Civil, Computer, Earth, Education, Energy, Environment, Economics, Electrics, Electronics, Food, Future Science, Geology, Health, History, Journalism, Law, Language, Life-Sciences, Literature & Art, Management, Materials, Mechanics, Medicine, Mathematics, Physics, Psychology, Pharmacy and Pathology, Philosophy, Shipping & Ocean, Sociology, Sports Sciences, Traffic and Transportation, Tourism and Restaurants, etc.. After 11 years of development, the company has made phenomenal progress through unremitting efforts. **Until** 2012, we have scholarly publishing services with more than 150 countries. Besides, the quality of papers has been further improved, which not only enhances the reputation of the journals, but also expands the **influences** of the company. Thank you for reading **at the end of this page**. If you are interested in our company and want to learn more, please spend some time on this site or contact us. And if you would like to **cooperate** with us, as our author, colleague, partner or in any other way, we **are** glad to hear from you.

- Materials Science and Engineering are the names of whole fields. This attempts to serve an entire field as an umbrella journal, which is kind of like having a "Journal of Science". The topic is really broad and it's hard to see such a journal as viable.
- The journal's website looks very unconvincing. It says there's a journal A and journal B is because it's been separated into two issues, which doesn't make sense. The list of editorial board members is also very strange, since it gives the country of the editor as opposed to institution, and the journal apparently doesn't have an editor-in-chief.

I'd avoid the publisher, especially if they're expecting you to pay for publication (if they're inviting you to submit, I would expect cheaper or maybe even free open access). You could try emailing some of the editorial board members to confirm.

Comment: Agree, except first bullet.  See how MIT calls their "MatSci" department.  Also, often "mat sci" is under engineering, not sciences.  This has to do with the history of the field (coming out of metallurgy departments, related to mechanical engineering).  [Oh...also it is irrelevant if you don't have page charges.  Don't put your work in journals like this.]

Comment: @guest fair point, will edit.

Comment: No worries. I shake your (wo)manly hand!

Comment: Revised bullet one is strong.