# David Publishing Company (DPC) legit or not?

Tags: publishers

Recently I completed my master's program in ICT from Tokai University, Tokyo, Japan.
I have received an email from David Publishing Company (DPC).
They wanted to publish my paper in their journal.
They sent me a similar email earlier but, I forgot to reply or take a look at it. And I received it again.
I don't know the publishing companies directly contact to publish papers in their journal.
I have a little experience working with ICTR, IEEE, IDW, Academia, etc. Rather I don't know much details about other journals.

I will be very thankful if someone helps to identify whether this company is legit or a scam.
Here is the link to the publishing company:
https://www.davidpublisher.com/Home/Journal/JTHM

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. Please be aware that we do not evaluate individual journals or publishers here (see [this FAQ](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3657/7734)). The linked question may help you though.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't come across this particular publisher before but a quick scan of the website seems to suggest that it might fall into the "predatory" category. One obvious indication is that they are soliciting you, someone who is objectively not a well known expert, to submit a paper.

Identifying predatory journals is something that has been discussed in general [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/83764/how-do-i-identify-predatory-and-low-quality-journals-with-bealls-list-gone-ho) and [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/123785/is-david-publishing-company-legit) (this question deals specifically with David Publishing Company).

Answer (score 1):

I don't need to check the link. The simple fact that you (someone who hasn't published in a journal and isn't an established scientist) received it is a sufficient indicator that this is a scam email.

Generally, if you intend to publish a manuscript, you simply submit it to a journal (of your choice). A journal asking you to submit something is, with few exceptions, a good indicator that you shouldn't do that.