# If a journal requires "Article Processing fee" does that make it a predatory journal?

Tags: publications, disreputable-publishers

If a journal take [article processing fee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_processing_charge) then does that mean the journal is [predatory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predatory_publishing)? or there are some other criteria to tell a journal as predatory?

Comment: This answers your 2nd question: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/83764/with-bealls-list-gone-how-can-i-tell-if-a-journal-is-spam

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, not all journals that charge to publish are predatory journals.  Some genuine open access journals charge article processing fees.  For example, the journals by [Copernicus](https://www.copernicus.org/), by the European Geophysical Union (EGU), charge moderate article processing fees.  These cover the costs of the publisher, which then makes the articles available open access free of charge.

To label a journal as predatory you need other (additional) criteria.

Comment: Some journals charge a "page fee" even when open access doesn't happen. Costs need to be covered _somehow_ if a journal is to remain viable.