# How do I cite my own PhD dissertation in a journal article?

Tags: citations, journals, paper-submission

I recently finished my PhD, and now I'm in the process of submitting a journal article on the work I did in the final few months of my degree. This work is an extension to some conference papers that I'd published earlier, and so I've cited them in my journal article stating how the submitted work differs from the published material. When I submitted the article to the journal, I mentioned in a cover letter that the same results/algorithms exist in my PhD dissertation.

After submission, I received a note from the journal to also cite my own PhD dissertation in the article, as there is a fair bit of similarity. The note said:

> You can resubmit after you have referenced the original article, and explained in your new article how this new work builds on your previous publication(s).

Considering the work presented in the journal article is not really an extension, and is pretty much the same as in the dissertation, how do I properly reference it? In my experience, I have not seen papers where the authors cited their own dissertation in the text.

Comment: Maybe a google scholar search for ["my dissertation"](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22my+dissertation%22) will give an example, close to your situation, that you can follow. Include one or more general terms for your field if you want something more field-specific.

Comment: Wording "the original article" may hint on some confusion. Are you sure you made it completely clear that the work in question is your dissertation and not a published paper? I think some clarification may be necessary

Answer (score 12):

In my experience (Theoretical Computer Science/Mathematical Logic) this issue is typically handled by having the sentence "This article is based on Chapter X of the author's PhD thesis \cite{myThesis}." as a stand-alone paragraph at the end of the introduction section.

Having just the plain sentence is consistent with the article having been edited only minimally to turn a chapter into a stand-alone article. If there are substantial differences, these can be pointed out in addition. Eg "We refer the reader to \cite{myThesis} for a much more detailed exposition of the proof."

Comment: In my field this sentence is usually part of the acknowledgement section. Not sure exactly why that is!

Comment: In my experience, this sentence is often a footnote on the first page. It's also often slightly extended by appending "written under the supervision of [name of Ph.D adviser]."

Comment: Here's an example from one of the top economics journals of using the footnote on the first page: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.3982/ECTA6248

Answer (score 6):

If the dissertation is "published" then cite it like any other work. Otherwise cite it by name and authors and mark the citation as (doctoral dissertation, U of the Universe, unpublished).

It might only take a note or a short paragraph somewhere to explain how the present paper is related to the dissertation. "Builds" was just boilerplate. In fact, the note you sent to the editors might be enough if it is incorporated in a "prior work" paragraph or two.

"Published" is a nebulous term for dissertations. It can mean other than "by a recognized publisher". For example, some dissertations are "published" by the university and available via the Library or by ProQuest/University Microfilms.

But, failure to cite the ideas is self plagiarism. When in doubt, cite, even if you think it is over-citation.

---

Some dissertations are nothing more than a collection of previously published work along with a description of how it fits together as a whole. In such a case, just cite the individual papers as you would those of any researcher. Such dissertations are common in some fields and are also sometimes known as "stapled" distributions.

Comment: I disagree with the part about citing the dissertation as a published work. My dissertation was three working papers. I certainly was not expected to cite it when I published that work. I simply had a note in the acknowledgment.

Comment: For a "cumulative" dissertation as you describe, @Dawn, it is enough to cite the individual papers as you suggest. The dissertation isn't really a new thing, taken in itself. The OP here didn't describe it as such. And I assume you mean three "published" working papers. Edited to clarify

Comment: No, I am suggesting the reverse. The dissertation was working papers. When publishing, the convention is to write something in the acknowledgment like: “The present research was originally conducted as part of the author’s dissertation work at The University of Research.”

Comment: @Buffy Out of curiosity, is it common in the US that PhD theses are *not* published? At least in Germany (and I think in many parts of Europe), in general they *must* be published. Of course, traditionally this just meant handing in 30 or so copies to be deposited at some main libraries, and nowadays it means publishing it at the university library's website + 5 or so copies handed in.

Comment: @Buffy as an example: "PhD dissertations are published or otherwise made available for distribution as proof of the candidate’s achievement, echoing a traditional European idea that the candidate for a doctorate must make a contribution to knowledge and cannot have a degree for making a discovery that is kept secret. Because of this, **restricting access to dissertations or delaying the release of the work (i.e. “embargoed”) only occurs in very exceptional cases**." https://gsas.harvard.edu/degree-requirements/dissertations/publishing-options

Comment: @user151413, some places all that is required is to have it sent to ProQuest which is a "sort of" publishing. It isn't that things are held as "secret", but just that formal publishing may not be required. But graduates often "mine" their dissertations for papers after the fact. And "published" is a fuzzy term. Is _available via ProQuest_ "published"? No peer review.

Comment: @Buffy What do you call "sort of" publishing? (I mean, what would be "real" publishing?) Is submitting 30 copies which get placed in some national libraries "sort of" or "real"?

Comment: @user151413, as I said, the meaning is fuzzy. Some would say yes, since it is probably available. Some would say no since there is no independent review. Fuzzy. In the US universities have their own rules. There is no national system.

Comment: @user151413 I believe the issue is about the generic sense of the word "publish/publication" and the specific academic sense. I am in the Netherlands; a PhD thesis would be "published" in the sense that a definitive version of the thesis is formally disseminated both in print (with dozens of copies) and digitally, but it is not expected to count as, e.g., a "prior publication" when submitting to a journal or be listed under "Publications" in the CV.

Comment: @jnanin I agree that it is subtle to ask whether this constitutes prior publication if you want to publish the result again (I agree it doesn't, which however doesn't mean it shouldn't be cited).  On the other hand, if someone published a result I had published prior in my PhD thesis, they had to cite it, because it *was* published prior.  So in that sense, it is just like any other published result.

Comment: @user151413 But that's equally true for working papers that are "published" on, say, Arxiv or SSRN. They can and should be cited as necessary, just like any other works, but that does not mean that the final peer-reviewed version of the paper has to cite its own earlier working paper version.

Answer (score 1):

> When I submitted the article to the journal, I mentioned in a cover letter that the same results/algorithms exist in my PhD dissertation.

The editor made a mistake.  Very probably an automated plagiarism check was performed without viewing the cover letter or examining the type of document the plagiarism check located.  The editor thought your dissertation was an article, which it obviously is not.

Are you sure this is a good quality journal?
[How do I identify predatory and low quality journals? With Beall's List gone, how can I tell if a journal is spam?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/83764/how-do-i-identify-predatory-and-low-quality-journals-with-bealls-list-gone-ho)

It is perfectly normal to cite your own dissertation the same way you would cite someone else's.

Once you have cited your dissertation and determined this is a good journal, you can write in your response letter that the submission is a portion of your dissertation and it is not previously published in any journal (assuming that's true.)

Comment: If the dissertation is published (which can mean many things - basically just that everyone can go and look it up in some library), then it should be cited.

Comment: I agree that this is a mistake by the editor. Obviously you can use the text from your dissertation with a minor note or citation somewhere in the article.

Comment: @Dawn But isn't that precisely the point, that it should be cited properly?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Hm, the editor might just have been sloppy or in a hurry.  In the quote, it also says "build on previous **publications**" (not: articles).

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally, PhD theses constitute a public proof of your abilities and therefore need to be published. (This is certainly true in the places in Europe I know, but a quick search revealed e.g. the same for [Harvard](https://gsas.harvard.edu/degree-requirements/dissertations/publishing-options), and I assume it is true for more US places as well).

The traditional way of this publication process would be to print a certain number of copies and hand them in at your library, which would then distribute it to some central libraries (national library etc.) which hold a copy of anything published in a country/region. There is no need to be able to order the thesis with a publisher, for it to have an ISBN number, etc.. (Semi-fun fact: When people started chasing German politician who plagiarized their PhD thesis, in some cases all copies were borrowed from those libraries and were never returned.)

These days, the publication process (at least in natural sciences) often consists in submitted an electronic version which is made available on the website of the university library.  (It might be that a reduced number of printed copies still needs to be handed in.)

In either case, this constitutes a publication which can be cited.  It should be cited like any other book, i.e.,

High Voltage, "On current and resistance", PhD thesis, Tesla University, Berlin, 2021,

or corresponding to the journal style.  If it is published on the library website, it makes a lot of sense to add the URL or (if existent) DOI.

Of course, if the PhD thesis is *not* published, this is different, and it need not be cited. (In fact, one might argue it *cannot* be cited, as it is not a publication.)  In any case, if you are unsure you should check with your university, most likely either the library or the graduation office.

Comment: True for _some_ US places, certainly. But there are no universal rules in the US.

Comment: @Buffy There are no universal rules e.g. in Germany either, in the sense of centrally imposed rules. Typically, each university makes their own rules for awarding PhD, and possibly departments can modify the rules. But I'm rather sure that all of those rules say that a PhD thesis must be published. I think this is simply the traditional perspective on a PhD thesis, see also the Harvard quote - that it is a publication, publicly demonstrating your qualification.

Comment: And, again, certainly true for Harvard. The US is not Germany.

Comment: @Buffy No doubt about that!  I guess in the US pretty much anything can call themselves a university and award degrees.

Comment: So, chauvinism now? Please. The standards here are pretty high generally.

Comment: @Buffy Sorry, this came across wrong. I know that the standards are pretty high in general. But there are also some rather mediocre places. So I was generally curious whether there are some official conditions to found a university, or in essence, anyone could open a place which can call themselves university and award degrees. (Whether people would pay for that, or anyone would take those degrees seriously, is a different story altogether.)

Comment: Seems https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Unaccredited_institutions_of_higher_learning_in_the_United_States  and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diploma_mills_in_the_United_States provides some information.

Comment: Quote: 'In 2004, a housecat named Colby Nolan was awarded an "Executive MBA" by Texas-based Trinity Southern University.'   ROFL!

Answer (score -4):

You could try pre-printing it and citing the preprint. Benefits are short time to `publication' (a couple of days, maximum, and only on a weekend) so very short delay to resubmission, moreover, the citation still counts for h-indices etc. I am sure that arXiv does theses as I have definitely read some there.

A proper citation could simply be a sentence like ``[type of result] [number or name if applicable] was developed in [citation], and is [restated/extended/some other word] here."

[citation] Your Name, Year, Your Dissertation Title, *Dissertation from [your univ.]*

This citation may be adapted if you do indeed arxiv it.

Comment: Putting the dissertation on the arXiv does not help with the OPs issue at all.

Comment: Not only was that *not* the sole content of my answer, but had you read more carefully, in combination with the rest of the answer it absolutely does aim to help -- here is a place to cite it from, and here is how to cite it, together following the conventions of normal self-citation practises in academic literature.