# Letter to editor type article

Tags: publications

Some journals have letter to editor type article. I checked a few papers the day between submission and acceptance is just 2 - 3 days. Does this mean it is easier to publish this type of paper? Also, does this mean the quality of paper is lower than other types?

Does anybody have experience about this type of paper?

This question is not at all related to [How do I identify predatory and low quality journals? With Beall's List gone, how can I tell if a journal is spam?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/83764)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I identify predatory and low quality journals? With Beall's List gone, how can I tell if a journal is spam?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/83764/how-do-i-identify-predatory-and-low-quality-journals-with-bealls-list-gone-ho)

Comment: I've never heard of a quality journal publishing a letter in less than a week.

Comment: In Physics, letters take longer to publish and are more likely to be rejected.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist The OP is talking about a letter _to the editor_ not a "letter". These letters are generally [responses to another article, opinions, or current events](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4548563/). As such, they may only be reviewed by the editor (instead of full peer-review) and may not count as "citable items," e.g. for analytics.

Comment: @user71659 That's not how it works in my discipline.  It's up to the asker to clarify.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist It certainly does exist in Physics: [How to talk to a non-specialist, Nature Physics](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41567-021-01473-z), [Comment on the paper by..., Physica A](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378437121007949)

Comment: @ user71659 Exactly except, citing. It is cited in my field.

Comment: @user71659 That is not a "letter." It is an "editorial."

Comment: Does anybody know how can I find a cover letter template specifically for "letter to editor" type journal?

Answer (score 2):

Each publication type has specific scope and requirements. You wouldn't be able to publish a *Regular Paper* as a *Letter to the Editor* just to shorten the publication time. And, no, it's not easier to publish a *Letter to the Editor*: it's likely the other way round.

Publishers have guidelines that report the requirements for each publication type. Check those for the journals you're interested in. For instance, here is what [*Journal of Physics A: Mathematical and General*](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/36/7/001) (a journal I've picked up at random) requires (I highlighted in bold some important points):

> This section of the journal publishes ***high quality*** short reports of important new results. **Letters are both timely and important enough to merit rapid publication**; they should not be more than 3500 words (6 journal pages) in length. The publication process of Letters is accelerated by using streamlined refereeing and production procedures. Accepted Letters benefit from higher visibility through being available free of charge on the journal web page to non-subscribers.
>
> Letters will normally be assessed by one senior referee, usually a
> board member, using the following criteria. To be accepted for
> publication, a Letter to the Editor should:
>
> **(i) present important new results (ii) be likely to stimulate further research (iii) be of interest to the wider mathematical or statistical physics community (iv) be sufficiently significant to justify accelerated publication.**
>
> **Serial publication of letters - where research is published as a series of letters rather than as full research papers - is not acceptable in the journal.**

You can expect similar requirements for other journals as well.

Comment: Thank you so much really. in composite structures nothing is written about Letter to editor requirements

Comment: So, how about the quality? we cant say that it has lower or higher quality than normal article right?

Comment: @AhmadTurani No, one can't say anything about the quality: you will find articles of variable quality in each category.

Comment: "streamlined proceedures" does not mean actual time to publication is faster - for APS it's slower.

Comment: OP is talking about actual ''letters'', a letter in the English language at least is a short journal article and not literally a letter.

Comment: @Tom There's two things called letters and everybody is getting confused, including this answer. A "letter" can be a short research paper that is otherwise complete. An "editorial letter" or "letter to the editor" is be a non-peer reviewed (or lightly reviewed) response to another paper, something that expresses an opinion, a report of news, etc., that is deemed to be relevant to readers.

Comment: @user71659 no one is getting confused: as I wrote, each journal has its guidelines for what is considered a letter. If you have a different take, please write an answer but don't answer in comments.

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0263822320325800#b0110   Look above the title! this paper published in 2 days. Actually, it is not bad paper!