# Is the Journal of Asian Health a predatory journal?

Tags: disreputable-publishers

I recently had a paper accepted to the [Journal of Asian Health](https://journalofasianhealth.org/index.php/jasianh). Their editorial team seems to consist of one professor, and it seems that they just published their first volume in 2021. However, they do seem to be published by Stanford or at least affiliated with them. Does this journal seem predatory and if so, is it even worth it to put this publication on my resume?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I identify predatory and low quality journals? With Beall's List gone, how can I tell if a journal is spam?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/83764/how-do-i-identify-predatory-and-low-quality-journals-with-bealls-list-gone-ho)

Comment: I disagree that this is a shopping question (voting to reopen).  This asks a specific question about the journal rather than simply seeking help choosing a journal.

Comment: @Ben https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4201/63475 https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3657/why-was-my-question-put-on-hold-for-shopping Evaluation of individual journals is included in the category of shopping questions. We don't want a collection of these questions for every possible journal

Comment: @BryanKrause As this comes up from time to time, why not introduce a canonical question about journal reputations? Predatory journals are not an irrelevant topic for people in academia.

Comment: @Sursula https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3824/what-potential-duplicate-targets-should-i-know-about-as-a-reviewer

Comment: @Ben this is clearly a shopping question as it asks for "assessment" but it should have been closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Sursula I've changed it to being closed as a duplicate of such a question.