# How to react when the editor responds to a withdrawal by asking for the LaTeX file?

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, editors

I submitted a manuscript to a journal, but due to an issue with that I asked the Editor-in-Chief and Associate Editor to withdraw the manuscript from further consideration. The response of the Editor-in-Chief was:

> Thank you for the message.
> Please send the latex file of the paper urgent to expedite the publication.
> Sorry for the delay

Now, what should I do?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/83764/how-do-i-identify-predatory-and-low-quality-journals-with-bealls-list-gone-ho

Comment: *I submitted a manuscript to a journal, but due to an issue with that ...* What you should do would surely depend on what the problem you had was.

Answer (score 20):

Just resend your email highlighting that it is a withdrawal.

Comment: Likely the editor got confused somehow, or hit the wrong button on the auto reply page. But if you withdraw you probably won't see any reviews.

Answer (score 1):

When someone writes you an unexpected message, you should write back and ask for clarification.  My guess is they have accepted the paper, but it could also be they got you confused with someone else.  I can think of a few more possibilities.

I have no idea if you think having an immediate acceptance in this journal is a good thing.  If you do, write back with the latex file attached and thanking the editor for dealing with whatever problems you are not telling us about. If you do not, reiterate the withdrawal.