# Is the "Journal of Innovations" in management a Reliable Source for Academic Research?

Tags: publications, journals, research-topic, management

I came across the Journal of Innovations in [specific subject area] (https://www.journal-innovations.com/) and am considering it as a potential source for my research. However, I'm uncertain about its reliability and reputation in the academic community.

Does anyone have any experience with this journal or insights into its editorial practices, peer-review process, and overall credibility? I would appreciate any information or feedback that can help me assess whether the Journal of Innovations is a trustworthy platform for scholarly publications. Thank you!

Comment: That might be a question for your supervisor and co-authors. Not being from your field, the journal homepage looks suspicious to me. Multiple typos / poor English / low APCs for OA / PayPal as the first payment option / an APC depending on the author number / a T&F publication until 2023 but now not longer with them / .... If in doubt, ask your local library as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/83764/how-do-i-identify-predatory-and-low-quality-journals-with-bealls-list-gone-ho